# Find domain and range of relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Find domain and range of relation : $\;R=\{ (a , b)\in\Bbb N\times\Bbb R^+\; :\; ⌊b⌋ −2 \le a\le⌊b⌋+2 \}\;$. $\Bbb R^+\;$ means real positive numbers and $\;\Bbb N\;$  natural numbers

Can someone explain it ? My teacher said something like you put a=b in this and there comes domain as Natural numbers? I dont understand this... I know for a fact that if we have Relation like <1,5> <4,6> then domain is 1,4 and range is 5,6 but I dont understand how to calculate this in this case...

Comment: Do you know *the definition* of domain and range of relation? Write it down in your question, at least.

Comment: I mean I know like domain is N in this case and range is R+... I think...

Comment: Yep, that is all. More interesting would have been to ask about the relation's **image** ...

Comment: I see but what if I didnt know that what i'm looking for is just in front of my eyes? My teacher doesn't accept short anwsers....

Answer (score 1):

In your question: $R=\{(a,b)∈\Bbb N×\Bbb R^+:⌊b⌋−2≤a≤⌊b⌋+2\} $
The first part: $(a,b)∈\Bbb N×\Bbb R^+$ means that *a* belongs to natural numbers and *b* belongs to positive real numbers.

So we can first limit the domain (values of *a*) to Natural numbers and range (values of *b*) to Real positive numbers.

But that is not enough to find the **actual** domain as *a* and *b* must also satisfy the condition given.
However in your case... $b∈\Bbb R^+$ so $b∈(0,∞)$ so for *a* also $a∈[0,∞)$ but only natural numbers.

So your domain is natural numbers and range is positive real numbers.